# Toad for Oracle: code analysis: rule warnings: underline color

Tags: oracle, toad

I would like to change the underline color of code analysis warnings in SQL editor from dark blue to something else. Can it be done?

See screenshot (under the measurements):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in your version. I see a block staple visible in your screenshot so you must be on 12.6 or earlier. In 12.7 and newer this is possible.

Comment: Great deduction :)
I didn't include version (I should have) but you are indeed right.
Could you please - for the sake of future generations - specify the option location in latest version?

Comment: In 12.7 and newer it's on the Editor|Font and Styling page in Options. On the Global tab select the Code Analysis item from the list box. Change the Background color to the right. You can also change the underline style. It defaults to squiggle as in prior versions.

Comment: I'll add too that the edit control changed between 12.6 and 12.7 so you'll need to recreate your theme unfortunately. It's going to default to white background and the styles are too different to convert your old settings to the new automatically.